# Dropdown-menu não funciona. jQuery.js em falta

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Recentemente estava a ter problema com o meu 'dropdown-menu' o menu não baixa quando pressionado.

Pelas pesquisas que fiz, descobri que não funciona devido à falta do ficheiro 'jQuery.js' no directório js.

A versão do bootstrap que baixei é o "bootstrap-3.3.6-dist" no site oficial e não conta o ficheiro jQuery.js

No directório js apenas tenho os seguintes ficheiros: bootstrap.js, bootstrap.min.js e o npm.js

Qual a versão correcta a baixar onde consta o jQuery ou onde baixo o ficheiro por si?

Comment: Pode obter o jquery a partir de CDN(content delivery networks), [como o proprio site do bootstrap sugere](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template). Ou a partir do site do [jquery](http://jquery.com/download). Ou [outras cdns](http://jquery.com/download/#other-cdns)

Comment: Baixe alguma versão inferior a 3.0.0, pois o Bootstrap ainda não oferece suporte para versão mais avançadas.